# How to create tables with linked columns in SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I'm trying to create a database for a simple C# application using SQL server.
I'm new to this.

This is what I had planned:

```
Clients: Client_ID, Client_Name, Client_Status
Employees: Emp_ID, Emp_Name, Emp_Role
Jobs: Job_ID, Job_Date, Client_ID, Employee_ID, Hours_Spent
```

How do I make the "Client_ID, Employee_ID" columns in table Jobs linked or connected the original ones in the tables Clients and Employees? Do I do it from SQL server management or from the C# code?

Comment: Search about `Foreign Key`.

Comment: You can use ORM - Entity Framework. With Code First you can create Foreign Key constraints  on the models. If you plan to spend a lot of time programming with .Net and Sql try to learn Entity. It makes life so much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this by creating foreign keys. It is most certainly NOT done in C#. These are database commands that affect the database. It has nothing to do with an application.

You can find the syntax here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189049.aspx

It seems like you might need to add at least one more table here. The way you have this you can't have more than employee working on a given job. I would move the employee columns to another table.

```
EmployeeJobs(Emp_ID, Job_ID, Hours_Spent)
```